# Error related to bidi or arabxetex: Command \XeTeX already defined

Tags: arabic, bidi, arabxetex

I get a non-fatal error when I run the following MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}

% Choose roman font (choosing the mapping so that ``-->“, '-->’ etc.).
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Gentium}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.90,Ligatures=NoCommon]{Courier}

% Greek (not strictly necessary since I just use Gentium for both Greek and Latin).
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Gentium} % GFS Porson

% Arabic
\usepackage[novoc,fdf2alif]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=2]{USAMA NASKH}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\renewcommand\poemcolsepskip{1cm}
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{\textarab{#1}}

\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}


\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{date}
\maketitle

text

\end{document}
```

The error message appears twice:

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/bidi/latex-xetex-bidi.def:122: L
 aTeX Error: Command \XeTeX already defined.
                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Apparently there is some issue related to `bidi` or `arabxetex`, because when I comment out those lines, the error messages go away.

Question: is there away to solve the problem without removing Arabic script functionality?

Comment: Remove `fontspec` and `bidi`. `arabxetex` loads them anyway. Probably also remove `xltxtra` as you almost certainly don't need it. Shouldn't you be using language definitions for Arabic, as well as American? Or does `xarabxetex` take care of that?

Comment: `fdf2alif` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

@cfr's comments on my question deserve to be upgraded to the answer, which I give here:

The solution, as @cfr suggested, was to stop loading `fontspec` and `bidi` independently of `arabxetex` and removing `xltxtra`. That meant that I also had to load `arabxetex` before I started defining the Greek and Roman font families (since the latter require `fontspec`).